# Falha no teste - setup.ts

Tags: react, jest

Galera,

Estou tentando rodar um teste do componente App, no entanto, o jest está interpretando o setup.ts como um teste. 
Já apontei ele como um setup no package.json, mas não funciona.

**Setup.ts**

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.6",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "23.3.12",
    "@types/node": "10.12.18",
    "@types/react": "16.7.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^6.4.4",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.6",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.3.1",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.2.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^7.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.7.0",
    "reactstrap": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.2",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup.ts",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/setup.ts",
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3"
  }
}
```

**App.test.ts**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from '../src/App';

describe('Testando o App Component', () => {
  it('Deve renderizar corretamente', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

[image: Erro]

Comment: Amigo, evite colocar imagens de texto. É muito ruim de ler, e fica difícil de tentar reproduzir o comportamento localmente. Procura usar as ferramentas de formatação para postar o código e os erros. Isso ajuda a comunidade a te ajudar...

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, já ajustei!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa informar ao `jest` para ignorar o seu setup.ts. Tente adicionar o seguinte no seu `package.json`

```js
...
"jest": {
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "__tests__/setup.ts"
    ]
}
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulepathignorepatterns-array-string